# Redirect output of one recursive query into another recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query, topological-sort

I wanted to find the topological sort of a DAG.

```
CREATE TABLE topo(
v1 int,
v2 int
);

INSERT INTO topo VALUES (1,3),(2,5),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,7),(6,5),(7,null)

WITH RECURSIVE path(S,d) AS(
 SELECT t1.v1, 0 FROM topo t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN topo AS t2 ON t1.v1=t2.v2 
 WHERE t2.v2 IS NULL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.v2, path.d + 1 FROM path INNER JOIN topo AS t1 ON 
 t1.v1=path.S
)
SELECT S FROM path GROUP BY S ORDER BY MAX(d);
```

This code gives the output of the topological order of a graph. Now I want to use this output into another recursive query to find the path from one vertex to another.

Can I use the output generated by this code into another recursive query?

Comment: Could you just get that path by adding a new field to the existing recursive CTE?

Comment: How? Suppose I want to get the path from 3 to 7. Is that possible without writing another recursive query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to your existing recursive sql to get path:

```
WITH RECURSIVE path AS(
 select 
   t1.v1 as start,
   t1.v2 as end,  
   CAST(t1.v1 as VARCHAR(30)) as path 
   0 as depth
 from topo t1 
   left outer join topo as t2 on t1.v1=t2.v2 
 where t2.v2 IS null

 UNION ALL
 select 
   path.start ,
   t1.v2 as end,
   path.path || '>' || t1.v1,       
   path.d + 1 
 from path 
   inner join topo as t1 on t1.v1=path.end
)
SELECT * FROM path
```

Just adding in a couple of more fields to track what's happening as you traverse your hierarchy. `Start` will be static from the first query. It will be `1` for every record since that is your starting point. `End` is whatever node you are currently working. `path` will concatenate the end node as each new one is found. `depth` will tell you how far you traversed.